# need to add html code so it's possible to se it in source view - with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have gallery! when you add image it fades in the gallery... works fine - i use .append(), but it also needs to be added so the added html code is visible in "source view" - I can't see it! I tried .html() in stead of .append(), but all i got is "replaced" html in div that is used as holder for all images.

Comment: what you mean by source view? If you use firefow, firebug will show you the added HTML.

Comment: If your problem is inspecting the DOM then consider using Firebug or Chrome inspector.

Answer (score 3):

**That is not possible.** 'View Source' shows the DOM that was loaded from the request, before any scripts started changing it.

Only inspecting of the 'real time DOM' will give the user the ability to see what is going on. In Chrome you can do it by right clicking the page:

[image]

In IE you could use the F12 Developer tool to select the element:
[image]

Comment: Note: The Firefox addon Web Developer has an option to 'View Generated Source' that will show post-server javascript changes.  It's pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't! Adding code to the DOM dynamically will not add it to the actual document, which is what "view as source" displays in all major browsers.

You will however see the changes in the console (firebug, dragonfly, Chrome inspector etc.)